# Corpus linguistics building can be considered as phd research topic in NLP for computer science engineer?

Tags: phd, thesis, computer-science

Receive my greetings everyone! I'm sorry if here is not the place for such questions.And excuse me for my english.I'am not native speaker.My concern is:I 'm recently graduated student in Computer Science. I want to continue with PHD in Natural Language Processing. I chose to do it with my Native language.I'm the first person to deal with this language in NLP. For that,I want to know if building corpus of my language can be considered as a topic of RESEARCH.But ,I need it,if I want to deal with advanced part of NLP such as POS tagging,Translation..... What is your point of view about my worries.Do you think ,building corpus only make me a researcher?

Comment: Why do you care about counting as a 'researcher'?    The answer will always be 'Yes for some purposes and no for other purposes'.

Comment: In general, building language resources is welcome and considered as NLP research ([example: LREC](https://lrec2022.lrec-conf.org/en/)). So in general it's probably possible to do a PhD on such a topic, but of course it's not guaranteed. Note that [low-resource languages](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/62868/64377) is also a subtopic in NLP. Mind that if there is no electronic resource available at all for your language, it's unlikely that you can reach the stage of advanced tasks like machine translation. It usually takes a lot of time just to build basic resources.

Comment: Also don't assume that it's easy simply because you know the language: building a good linguistic resource requires some skills and knowledge, like any research.

Comment: Thank you so much! My language is low-resource language.I can not deal with advanced part such as machine translation.The reason,I'm asking if I can build its corpus for futur researchers in NLP (in my language ) to use it.Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

You are getting a bit ahead of the game here. Your question is one for an advisor after (or as) you get accepted into a doctoral program. Research topic is normally negotiated with the advisor so that you get proper advice.

But, even if you don't convince an advisor to work with you on this topic, if you can find something mutually agreeable, then you can always go back to that topic later after you have more experience.

But don't make any particular topic a precondition for working with an advisor. First things first.

As for the topic itself, it might be possible or not depending on the bigger picture surrounding it. What is the research question? What will be gained by answering it. Those are things to discuss with an advisor.